# Dream - Eating matzah

Tags: food, matzah, dream

Does anyone know what it means if you dream about eating matzah? My Shabbat dream this afternoon was that my sister and I were eating matzah. We each took a piece.

Thank you.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10842

Comment: You would need to ask a rav who is an expert in dreams, preferably one who knows you and your circumstances. It could be dependent on your family relationships. As an example, it could mean a reconciliation with a sibling that you do not have a good relationship with or someone in your family returning to Yiddishkeit. *This is just a possibility off the top of my head since I know nothing of you or your family*

Comment: If I remember correctly it is recommended you should only l ask a person who likes you , or whom you have a gift, to interpret your dream (since the interpretation is the thing that affects you, not the dream itself (so it someone interprets it not good it can have a not good effect, but it is interpreted good then it is good))

Answer (score 1):

Your dream means that You and your sister are good friends, and that anything negative between you has been removed. This is shown by your shared eating together from the same source and that matzah is representative of humility. Two humble people, can easily be friends. It also shows that since matzah is flat, both of you will not be subject to being overweight, or at least you will not be overweight in the eyes of those who would see you. Shabbos afternoon is the time of secret of secrets. Marriage is also a secret and bread is a symbol of a wife. This means that your soul and your sister's soul have been blessed to be happily married.

The Gemara in Brachos chapter 9 has an entire section dealing with the rules of dream interpretation.Here are a few things mentioned there:

1. A dream turns out according to how it is interpreted.
2. Therefore, one should always tell their dream to a friend so they will receive a good interpretation.
3. Even bad things in a dream (like seeing someone's nose fall off, death etc.) can be easily (and should be) interpreted to mean something good, and that's how it will turn out.
4. Even if someone knows this rule and specifically tries to explain the dream in a positive way just because they want to, it still works! It is not cheating. However, the details of the dream should somewhat match the interpretation. (make sense)

But, it also says:

5. There is always some silliness (false facts) in every dream.
6. A person dreams about what they think of during the day. For instance, dreaming (on Shabbos afternoon) about eating matzah with a sister, could simply be because you just (or usually) ate the third meal with her and you usually use two matzos as sheleimos. So, your mind had that thought in it already and you dreamed about it naturally.

However, I stand by my first interpretation at the beginning of this answer. I am sure that is how it will turn out. :)

Comment: David Kenner, again a beautiful, well-researched and thoughtful answer.  I thank you, Sir.  Shavuah Tov .

Comment: @devorah You are most very welcome. :)