# God appearing in dreams?

Tags: dream

Is it possible that God appears to people in dreams these days? Can a person who spoke to Hashem in a dream consider this as a real dialog with God or should we instead consider it as pure work of our subconscious and imagination? Is there anything Chazal said about it?

Comment: More generally: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10502/170

Answer (score -1):

1. Yas, many people see/imagine G-d in dreams in different forms. And Yes, people might think it is real, just as the Jurassic Park III movie.
2. Since the destruction of the first Temple, G-d does not prophecize people, so a dream of speaking to G-d is surely a hoax.

Comment: "Since the destruction of the first Temple, G-d does not prophecize people"? What is your source? At least four of the Biblical prophets come from after the destruction

Comment: But Chazal say that dreams are some form of Nevuah. Maybe it’s still actually G-d speaking, but not the same as in a proper prophecy?

Comment: THis is what I commented on Eliyahoo: 
"חלומות שווא ידברו" - the Halachic approach is not to take it seriously. Funny, as the Gemmorah says the dreams are 1/60 of a prophecy, meaning 59/60 is personal imagination and the rule is that we always follow the MAJORITY! :)

Comment: Does Gemmorah speak about the likelihood of a dream being a prophecy, or that 1/60 of a dream is a prophecy?

Comment: @DanWeisberg I think every 60th word is true. You should count the words and then make up the prophecy message.  :)

Comment: @Al Berko, lol:)